# mix.compile returns error (Mix) Could not compile "src/gettext_po_parser.yrl" because the application "parsetools" could not be found

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

```
mix compile
==> gettext
could not compile dependency :gettext, "mix compile" failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile gettext", update it with "mix dep
s.update gettext" or clean it with "mix deps.clean gettext"
==> oblako
** (Mix) Could not compile "src/gettext_po_parser.yrl" because the application "parsetools" could not be found. This may happen if your package manager
 broke Erlang into multiple packages and may be fixed by installing the missing "parsetools" package for Erlang.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install erlang
```

solves the problem